# react-id-swiper not working for 3d coverflow

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, swiper.js

I'm trying to integrate the 3d cover flow for the project, but the coverflow not working as expected, I included image and code. Thanks in Advance for the help!

I have tried using the lastest package, i found that is not working, so i tried these old version, that also not working, the version which i used is "react-id-swiper": "2.3.2", "swiper": "^6.1.2".

code :

```
import React from 'react'
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import 'react-id-swiper/lib/styles/css/swiper.css';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{

    render() {

        const params = {
            effect: 'coverflow',
            grabCursor: true,
            centeredSlides: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            coverflowEffect: {
                rotate: 50,
                stretch: 0,
                depth: 100,
                modifier: 1,
                slideShadows: true
            },
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination'
            }
        }

        return (
          <React.Fragment >
              <Swiper {...params}>
                  <div style={{ backgroundImage:'url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1)' }} />
                  <div style={{ backgroundImage:'url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/2)' }} />
                  <div style={{ backgroundImage:'url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/3)' }} />
                  <div style={{ backgroundImage:'url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/4)' }} />
                  <div style={{ backgroundImage:'url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/5)' }} />
              </Swiper>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
    };

}

export default App;
```

output :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is it going brother. I also had the same problem and I realized one of the reason is that the latest of version of the `swiper` package is missing some css (you need the `swiper` package if you want to use `react-id-swiper`). For `react-id-swiper` it is okay to install the latest version, but downgraded the `swiper` package to 5.3.8 did the trick.

Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: I'm doing great Bro, Thanks for your help Dude!